# Использование функции base64_decode

Tags: php

```
$str='pof ho poff rg poffff ';
echo base64_encode($str);
echo base64_decode($str);
```

Почему не выходит исходная строка?
Когда нужно использовать функцию base64_encode, а когда сrypt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что при кодировании результат не сохраняется в $str
Вот так должно выйти

```
$str='pof ho poff rg poffff ';
$str = base64_encode($str);
echo $str;
echo base64_decode($str);
```